# bind(this) and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, oop

After reading some solutions, I came up with this:

```
class Car{
    constructor(carTag, throttle, yPosition){
        this.carTag = carTag
        this.carTag = new Image()
        this.throttle = throttle
        this.yPosition = yPosition
    }

    //Animate method that will animate cars across the screen
    animate(){
        const ref = this;
        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
            ref.animate();
        });
        const canvas = document.getElementById("gameboard");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let xPosition = canvas.width;
        setTimeout (function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, xPosition, ref.yPosition);  
            ctx.drawImage(ref.carTag, xPosition, ref.yPosition);                    
            xPosition -= 4;
            console.log(xPosition);
       }, 1000/ref.throttle);
    }
}

const cars = new Car;
cars.carTag.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png";
cars.throttle = 2000;
cars.yPosition = 0;
cars.animate();
```

The problem I am still stumped on is why my car image is stuck in one position and not animating.  Why is bind(this) interfering with requestAnimationFrame?

update: The latest version of this method doesn't produce error messages.  But for some reason, the xPosition isn't updated which moves the car image left.  I tried putting requestAnimationFrame to the bottom of the method, same result.

Comment: how do you start the animation?

Comment: Where's the first call to `animate`?

Comment: What is suppose to happen is that once the function is called, the image gets drawn then reqestAnimationFrame is called which loops the function to drawn another image.

Comment: I didn't add it, but for my test I did this.  const cars = new Cars;  cars.animate();

Comment: What's with the `setTimeout`? don't do both that and `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: The reason I used setTimeout is because I want my car to go at varying speeds.  Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Add `const cars = new Cars; cars.animate();` then make your post as a [mcve] by clicking the bracket button:`<>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Thanks everyone!

```
  class Car{
    constructor(carTag, throttle, yPosition, xPosition, canvas, ctx){
        //carTag property
        this.carTag = carTag
        this.carTag = new Image()
        //throttle property
        this.throttle = throttle
        //yPosition property
        this.yPosition = yPosition
        //canvas, ctx property connecting with DOM
        this.canvas = canvas
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("gameboard");
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        //xPosition property
        this.xPosition = xPosition
       this.xPosition = this.canvas.width;
    }

    //Animate method that will animate cars across the screen
    animate(){
        const ref = this;
        setTimeout (function(){
            ref.canvas.width = ref.canvas.width;  
            ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.carTag, ref.xPosition, ref.yPosition);                    
            ref.xPosition -= 4;
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                ref.animate();
           });
       }, 1000/ref.throttle);
    }
}

const cars = new Car;
cars.carTag.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png";
cars.throttle = 2000;
cars.yPosition = 0;
cars.animate();
```